# Why does iptables work with /16 netmask but not with /14?

Tags: iptables

I have a server with one of the network interfaces cofigured like this:

```
inet addr:10.101.21.71  Bcast:10.101.21.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I want to access it from another subnet `10.100.0.0/16`. PC from which I've tested is configured like this:

```
inet addr:10.100.140.6  Bcast:10.100.140.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

When I add next rule to `iptables` on my server - everything works:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.100.0.0/16 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

But when I switch that tule for another

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.100.0.0/14 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

it stops working.

The question is - why doesn't it work with second rule but works with first? 
As I understand - `10.100.0.0/14` subnet can have hosts from `10.100.0.1` to `10.103.255.254`, and `10.100.140.6` is one of them.

Does `iptables` allow access only from networks that *exactly* matches it's rules?

Comment: Netmask isn’t included in the TCP headers, so iptables doesn’t know what the “subnet” is of the source address. So it can’t be that iptables only allows access from specific netmasks. In theory both rules should work, so something must be being overlooked.

Comment: Why not just make the rule allow a range of ip addresses which in your case is 10.100.0.0 - 10.103.255.255?

Comment: You're _appending_ to the INPUT rule chain. Is there something already present that blocks the traffic you're trying to match?

Comment: @roaima I have `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP`, but It's always in the end of the chain, in both cases `/14` and `/16` rules come before that. Other than that there are only `ACCEPT` rules.

Comment: Is it possible that you also need to adjust some other rules (like OUTPUT) to make it working? Judging from interfaces' configurations you are showing above you also likely have router between the two. Is it configured correctly?

Comment: BTW you can try TRACE target from raw table on source IP address 10.100.140.6 to check what rules it hits... See man iptables-extensions for details

Comment: @Tomek No, the only thing I change is netmask of that rule. Rule position in chain is the same, and I don't add other rules. About router - I don't have access to it's configuration, but judging by the fact that it works with `/16` rule I assume that problem is not in routing.

Comment: You say you're trying from another subnet `10.100.0.0/16`, and you say the PC is configured as `inet addr:10.100.140.6  Bcast:10.100.140.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`; however that is 10.100.140.0/24, not 10.100.0.0/16. Is there a router between that PC and the server?